# useSubscription is not listening for subscriptions in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a subscription server that is working, and if i test it on the playground of the browser it works, but now when i try to use the `useSubscription` hook from `apollo` it is not working. Here is what my `client` looks like:

```
const requestLink = new ApolloLink(
  (operation, forward) =>
    new Observable((observer) => {
      let handle: any;
      Promise.resolve(operation)
        .then(async (operation) => {
          const jwt = await retrieve(KEYS.TOKEN_KEY);
          if (jwt) {
            operation.setContext({
              headers: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
              },
            });
          }
        })
        .then(() => {
          handle = forward(operation).subscribe({
            next: observer.next.bind(observer),
            error: observer.error.bind(observer),
            complete: observer.complete.bind(observer),
          });
        })
        .catch(observer.error.bind(observer));
      return () => {
        if (handle) handle.unsubscribe();
      };
    })
);

const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(
  createClient({
    url: `wss://${serverDomain}/graphql`,
  })
);

const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: `https://${serverDomain}/graphql`,
  credentials: "include",
});

const splitLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
      definition.operation === "subscription"
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  ApolloLink.from([requestLink, httpLink])
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: splitLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  credentials: "include",
});
```

This is how I'm subscribing to new subscriptions in a react-native component:

```
 const { me } = useMeStore();
  const { data, loading } = useSubscription(OnNewFriendRequestDocument, {
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    variables: {
      input: { id: me?.id || "" },
    },
  });
  console.log({ data, loading });
```

And it seems like this subscription is not listening to new subscriptions that are coming in. What maybe possibly the issue here.